# Laravel unit test validation

Tags: laravel, validation, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to unit test my method with the following validation rules.

```php
$rules = [
    'image_id' => 'required|exists:images,id'
];
```

**Test**

```php
$formData = [
    'title' => 'test regulatory update',
    'body' => 'test body',
    'image_id' => 1000,
    'file_id' => 3000,
    'enforce_date' => '2018-01-01',
    'region_id' => 4000
];

$trans = $this->getRealTranslator();
$v = new Validator($trans, array('image_id' => 1000), array('image_id' => 'exists:images,id'));
$validatorMock = Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Validation\PresenceVerifierInterface');
$validatorMock->shouldReceive('setConnection')->once()->with(null);
$validatorMock->shouldReceive('getCount')
    ->once()
    ->with('images', 'id', 1000, null, null, [])
    ->andReturn(true);
$v->setPresenceVerifier($validatorMock);

$response = $this->call('POST', '/regulatory', $formData);
$statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
$this->assertEquals(200, $statusCode);
$this->assertTrue($v->passes());
```

When running my test, I get the following error.

> testing.ERROR: exception
>   'Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidationException' with message
>   'The given data failed to pass validation.'

My question is, how can I mock the validation to see that the image id of 1000 exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I use for this is a factory. If you place this in your database/factories/ModelFactory.php

```php
$factory->define(App\Image::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'id' => $faker->number,
    ];
});
```

Then you can change your `image_id` in your `form_data` array to this:

```php
'image_id' => factory(App\Image::class)->create([
    'id' => 1000
]),
```

A factory will generate a database row, so the validation if it exists, will pass.

The array, containing `'id' => 1000`, you sent along with the create method on factory overrides the factory generated data. This means the factory generates an image row with the id 1000.